# Locking for multiple nodes in c#

Tags: c#, locking

I have an application with 4 nodes that utilizes the scale-out feature. Within this application, I have a specific method or function that should only be executed by a single instance, while the other instances should skip it.

I would greatly appreciate it if you could suggest some intelligent solutions for this scenario.

Thank you.

One solution that I have considered is using a database table with a column called "Status." Each node would first check the status attribute, and if it is set to "In-Progress," the method will be skipped. On the other hand, if the status is not "In-Progress," the method will be executed.

Comment: Using a database is a common solution, especially if your app already uses a database that has the right kind of locking behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some kind of a distributed lock for such a thing, e.g.: https://github.com/madelson/DistributedLock

Or as a more advanced solution, you could use a [Hangfire](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire) job, which can handle similar scenarios.